# When i split a list in a for loop to make it readable, it loses all but the last line when i try to use it outside of the loop

Tags: python

When I do this:

```
DataList = open("database.csv").readlines()

for x in DataList:
    x.split(",")
    print(x)
print(x)
```

The first print(x) produces all of the lines in the document, nicely placed in a list. Then somehow all but the last line in the list are lost when performing the second print. It's really bugging me and I can't figure out a way to split the text from the document into an easily readable list. Can anyone help?

edit: Since people were asking for extra data and I STILL can't get it to work, here's some extra code:

```
varBox = StringVar()
varBox.set("Click To Change")
Option = OptionMenu(self, varBox, data)
Option.grid( sticky=W)
```

I need each line of the list to show as one option in this menu, i currently can't figure out how, even after all the help.

Comment: a sample of the data with expected outcome would help. Please ate that python has a csv module. If I were you just I would import it and use the csvreader. I believe you won't be need to use split method anymore

Comment: No, the first `print` doesn't produce _all_ the lines placed in a list, it prints individual lines one by one. Also, that `x.split` is a no-op, it doesn't change `x`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `x` is going to be a different element of the list in every loop, so in the first loop it will be `DataList[0]`, in the second it will be `DataList[1]` and so on. So, when you `print(x)` after the for block is done, `x` will still have the last value of DataList.
Also, `.split()` is not collateral, so it'll not affect `x` itself, it'll return a new list.

If you want to store every splitted line in a separate list you need to do it inside the for block, like:

```
splitted_lines = []
for x in DataList:
    splitted_lines.append(x.split(","))
print splitted_lines
```

Comment: or comprehension: `splitted_lines = [x.split(",") for x in DataList]`

Answer (score 1):

Correct your code to this:

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split(','))
```

This assumes that what you really want is for each line of the CSV to be split into individual elements.

Also, consider using the `csv` module as most CSV documents will REALLY contain quote-comma delimited files, so if you have a line like `"LAST, FIRST", "123 MAIN ST"`, then the basic split will give you 3 elements:  `['"LAST', 'FIRST"', '"123 MAIN ST"']` while the `csv` module will give you `['LAST, FIRST', '123 MAIN ST']`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
   with open ('database.csv', 'r') as csv_data
        data_file= csv.reader(csv_data)
        data= list(data_file)
```

Comment: use the  with open method as well

Comment: can you fix your typo in your code? and explain a little more. using csv is a good suggestion, but without explanation (and with the error), the answer is not very useful